# mongo db query get documents befor and after

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have the ObjectID of a document, how can I get the documents, that are before and after that document something like

```
db.getCollection('example').find({})
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongo's `ObjectId` is mostly monotonically increasing, on very rare occasions it's not like if you insert 2 documents at the exact same millisecond the "random" bit value added to it could technically break this. but this situation is *very* *very* rare.

So now you can query documents based this quality. for example this is how you'd fetch the `x` previous documents:

```
const id = ObjectId('xyz');
const documentsBefore = await db.getCollection('example').find(
    { _id: { $lt: id } })
    .sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(x).toArray();
```

Or documents after (he `sort` order and the query needs to change )

```
const id = ObjectId('xyz');
const documentsAfter = await db.getCollection('example').find(
    { _id: { $gt: id } })
    .sort({ _id: 1 }).limit(x).toArray();
```